Display data into modal form through django
I am very much new to django. I am trying to display the details of a student record in a modal form once details button clicked. But it is showing an empty modal form. Below is the code snippet. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong here. Thanks in advance.
Here are the views
def student(request):
    students = Student.objects.values("standard__standard_name", "studentid","firstname","lastname","status","nationality","Gender")
    return render(request, 'student.html', { 'students':students })

def student_detail(request, studentid):
    try:
        student_object = Student.objects.filter(studentid=studentid)
        student = student_object.values("studentid","firstname","lastname","standard__standard_name","status","nationality","dob","Gender","religion","parent__parentid")
        print(student)
    except student.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404('student not found')
    return render(request, 'student_detail.html', {'student':student})

student.html snippet
     <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="show-students-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="show-students" tabindex="0">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Standard</th>
          <th>Gender</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Nationality</th>
          {% for student in students %}
          <div class="studentname">
            <tr>
              <td>{{ student.firstname |capfirst }} {{ student.lastname |capfirst }}</td></a>
              <td>{{ student.standard__standard_name }}</td>
              <td>{{ student.Gender }} </td>
              <td>{{ student.status }} </td>
              <td>{{ student.nationality }} </td>
              <td><button type="button" class="modalbtn btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#studentModal" onclick="localtion.href='/student/<studentid>/detail/ student.studentid'">Details</button></td>
            </tr>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
        </table>
        <div class="modal" id="studentModal">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

              <!-- Modal Header -->
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="studentModal">{{ student.firstname }}</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>

              <!-- Modal body -->
              <div class="modal-body">

                {% include 'student_detail.html' %}
              </div>

              <!-- Modal footer -->
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

student_detail.html

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" >
  {% for s in student %}
  <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <td>{{ s.firstname |capfirst }} {{ s.lastname|capfirst }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th>FirstName</th>
      <td>{{ s.firstname }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th>LastName</th>
      <td>{{ s.lastname }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th>Standard</th>
      <td>{{ s.standard__standard_name }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th>DOB</th>
      <td>{{ s.dob }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <td>{{ s.Gender }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th>Nationality</th>
      <td>{{ s.nationality }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th>Religion</th>
      <td>{{ s.religion }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Parent</th>
    <td>
      {{ s.parent__parentid }}
    </td>
</tr>
  {% endfor %}
 
</table>


urls.py
    path('student/', views.student, name='student'),
    path('student/<studentid>/detail/', views.student_detail, name='student_detail'),


So what is not working? You here define two views?

when I click on detail button, the empty modal window appears. Yes, one view is for complete student table and another one is for filtered one

I think know what the problem is. In the student detail page, you are passing only one student!
So why are you exactly looping?????
your tags should be like:
{{student.first_name}}
{{student.last_name}}

But its not the case, cause if you loop through an student obj, you are going to get an error.
The thing is that you are looping through students while you are not even passing it to the template!
I have some other suggestions too!
Your url for student_detail :
path('student/<int:studentid>/detail/', views.student_detail, name='student_detail')

I just added and int before studentid , i think its a better practice,
The other suggestion is to use django tags and an a tag insted of js in your details button:
<a href="{% url 'student_detail' %}">Details</a>

In these cases I myself prefer a tags rather than buttons

Thanks for your suggestion. modal form appears with all the table headers but no data.

Well maybe there is no data! go to the admin panel and add some data manually!
